# Kafka HDFS Sink Connector Protobuf not being written

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, protocol-buffers, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use the Kafka HDFS 3 sink connector to write protobuf binary files to the HDFS. However, the connector keeps writing avro files.

I have setup my sink connector with the following config

```
{
    "name": "hdfs3-connector-test",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs3.Hdfs3SinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "testproto",
        "hdfs.url": "hdfs://10.8.0.1:9000",
        "flush.size": "3",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://10.8.0.1:8081",
        "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "10.8.0.1:9092",
        "confluent.topic.replication.factor": "1",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true"
    }
}
```

as you can see I am using the ProtobufConverter for the value converter, and the plugin is installed. (Is the ProtobufConverter converting to Avro file format?).

I also registered my schema and sent data to the topic using the following Java file:

```
package app;

import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import test.Test.*;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try { 
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "10.8.0.1:9092");
            props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
            props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer.class.getName());
            props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://10.8.0.1:8081");

            KafkaProducer<String, MyMsg> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, MyMsg>(props);
            String topic = "testproto";
            String key = "testkey";
            MyMsg m = MyMsg.newBuilder().setF1("testing").build();
            ProducerRecord<String, MyMsg> record = new ProducerRecord<String, MyMsg>(topic, key, m);
            producer.send(record).get();
            producer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

here is my proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";
package test;

message MyMsg {
    string f1 = 1;
}
```

So my question is, is this correct? Can I only write Avro files to the HDFS using this connector? Or is my configuration incorrect and I should be expecting protobuf files in the HDFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `format.class` config,

> format.class is
> The format class to use when writing data to the store. Format classes implement the io.confluent.connect.storage.format.Format interface.

> Type: class
> Default: io.confluent.connect.hdfs3.avro.AvroFormat
> Importance: high
> These classes are available by default:

> io.confluent.connect.hdfs3.avro.AvroFormat
> io.confluent.connect.hdfs3.json.JsonFormat
> io.confluent.connect.hdfs3.parquet.ParquetFormat
> io.confluent.connect.hdfs3.string.StringFormat

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-hdfs3-sink/current/configuration_options.html#hdfs3-config-options

Comment: Good catch. It seems like there is no protobuf support for the format.class for the time being.

Comment: It could be implemented I guess as the code is provided in github

Comment: If my answer helped you should accept it or at least +1 it, thanks

Comment: The HDFS3 connector code is not in Github.

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/tree/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/hdfs